# Customize the Outlook Web App (OWA) Overall Theme in Exchange 2013

Tags: exchange-2013, outlook-web-app

I am not talking about the individual user themes they can pick for their mailbox but rather the overall theme for OWA pages like login or expiredpassword, etc.

So far I have found the directory where the default base theme is located:

..\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V15\FrontEnd\HttpProxy\owa\auth\15.0.712\themes

This has two directories "base" and "resources" which contain the images, css, etc.,
I can obviously go into that directory and swap out images / change css to customize it.
This method is described here:
[Customize Outlook Web App](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee633483(v=exchg.150).aspx)

Here is a screenshot of the default theme owa login page (one of the pages I'd like to customize):

[image: Outlook Web App Login]

There just seems like there has got to be a better way to do this.

Does anyone know how to create a custom theme for OWA on Exchange Server 2013?
Also if it is possible, how to switch between themes?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This might help: http://careexchange.in/how-to-customize-the-outlook-web-app-owasign-in-page-in-exchange-2013/ but I'm not aware of a way to change a sign-in page theme like you can change to a different theme within OWA